# Storing a .jks file in Fabric profile

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, jks, fabric8

In our **Apache Camel** project, we are consuming a rest service which requires a `.jks` file.

- Currently we are storing `.jks` file in a physical location and referring to that in Camel project.  But it can't be used always, as we may be having access to the Fuse Management Console only and not to the physical location accessible from management console.
- Another option is to store key file within bundle, which is can't be employed because, certificate may change based on the environment.

In this scenario, what can be a better solution to store key file?

**Note**

- One option about which I thought was, storing `.jks` file within **fabric profile**. But could n't find any way to do that. Is it possible to store a file in Fabric profile?

Answer (score 1):

What about storing the `.jks` in a java package and reading it as a resource?
You bundle imports `org.niyasc.jks` and loads the file from there. The bundle need not to change between environments.

Then you write 2 bundles to provide the same package `org.niyasc.jks`, one with production file and one with test file.

**Production env**:
RestConsumerBundle + ProductionJksProviderBundle

**Test env**:
RestConsumerBundle + TestJksProviderBundle

Mind that deploying both of them may be possible and RestConsumerBundle will be bound to the first deployed bundle. You can eventually play with OSGi directives to give priority to one of them.

**EDIT**:
A more elegant solution would be creating an OSGi service which exposes the `.jks` as an `InputStream` or `byte[]`. You can even play with JNDI if you feel to.
From Blueprint declare the dependency as mandatory, so your bundle will not start if the service is not available.

```
<!-- RestConsumerBundle -->
<reference id="jksProvider"
           interface="org.niyasc.jks.Provider"
           availability="mandatory"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Storing the JKS files in the Fuse profile could be a good idea.

If you have a broker profile created, such as "mq-broker-Group.BrokerName", take a look at it via the Fuse Web Console.

You can then access the jks file as a resource in the property file, as in "truststore.file=profile:truststore.jks"

And also check the "Customizing the SSL keystore.jks and truststore.jks file" section of this chapter:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/html/fabric_guide/mq#MQ-BrokerConfig

It has some good pointers.

Regarding how to add files to a Fabric profile, you can store any resources under src/main/fabric8 and use the fabric8 Maven plugin. For more, see: 
https://fabric8.io/gitbook/mavenPlugin.html

-Codrin